# How to execute multiple statement in single query to update the table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to run the two select statement and pass the value to if condition and execute the update query. When i run without update query it's working.

**Without Update Query: (working)**

```
select (select @acc_id := account_id from table1 where book='xyz') as tab1, (select
@id := account_id from table2 where account_id = (select
@acc_id)) as tab2, (select if(((select @acc_id) = (select @id)), 'Valid', 'Invalid')) as test;
```

**With Update Query: (not working)**

```
select (select @acc_id := account_id from table1 where book='xyz') as tab1, (select
@id := account_id from table2 where account_id = (select
@acc_id)) as tab2, (select if(((select @acc_id) = (select @id)), (update table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.account_id=t2.account_id set t2.index1='value1', t2.index2='value2' where t1.book in ('xyz')), 'Invalid')) as test1;
```

I refer some threads but i can't solve this issue.

Comment: You cannot run a select and update statement together like this. Can you explain what you are trying to do and add sample data as text to your question together with expected result

Comment: I want to get the account id from table1 and table2. If both account id are matched then the update query need to run. @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

You might just need a simple update statement

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from table1;
+------------+------+
| account_id | book |
+------------+------+
|          1 | xyz  |
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from table2;
+------------+--------+--------+
| account_id | index1 | index2 |
+------------+--------+--------+
|          2 | NULL   | NULL   |
|          1 | NULL   | NULL   |
+------------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.account_id = t1.account_id
    -> set index1 = 'valu1',index2 = 'valu2'
    -> where t1.book = 'xyz';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from table2;
+------------+--------+--------+
| account_id | index1 | index2 |
+------------+--------+--------+
|          2 | NULL   | NULL   |
|          1 | valu1  | valu2  |
+------------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: if both account_id matched, i want to update the query if else, I would like to run insert query. Note: Second table doesn't have the foreign key (If anything updated manually in UI then only it added the accout_id.